# Can I parse HTML at a target page and jump to a link inside it instead?

Tags: php, html, regex, perl

The short version of my question is whether code can be written so that, instead of opening a page, it parses that page and opens a link on it instead? I've read a little bit about using PHP or Perl or other tools to parse HTML; is this something that could be done with tools like that?

I maintain some pages that include links to a fixed list of language-specific documents. The format is consistent along the lines of this (in generic fashion) with the line commented out if that document is not yet posted:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="(en_US link)">English</a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="(bg_BG link)">Bulgarian</a></li> --> 
    <!-- <li><a href="(zh_CN link)">Chinese - Simplified</a></li> --> 
    <li><a href="(zn_TW link)">Chinese - Traditional</a></li> 
    ... etc.
</ul>
```

Someone else has links to these pages.

Given one of these and knowing the language desired, could they find that link in the page and jump to it instead if that line is not commented out? Writing a regex would be easy because these embedded URLs all end with `xx_XX.pdf` using whatever the language/locale is.

I'm not trying to figure out what the code would be, just whether that's something one could write if they have the right tools and right knowledge.

Comment: The short version of the answer is yes, except that the original page must be fetched *as well* as the linked pages. There is no way to know what URLs a pages links to without fetching it first

Comment: There's no need to use HTML entities within code sections on  Stack Overflow. We use a version of [***Markdown***](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and there is a page here on [***Markdown Editing Help***](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to describe how the pattern is consistent across these links and thought that would make it easier to visualize.

Comment: What I mean is that *markdown* allows you to add preformatted data that may include HTML tags which are displayed literally. Look at how I've edited your question

Comment: Got it - I had to edit several times to get it to where I had it originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't give very much detail, but yes, it sounds like this is possible

Traditionally, PHP is a server-side language while Perl is more often used on the client side. It would be a bad idea to implement this on a web server system, but if you are thinking of an HTTP *client* then it is feasible in pretty much any language

If you don't understand the distinction between **client** and **server** then please ask

Comment: Thanks. This wouldn't get implemented at my end and I don't know what the other side looks like - I just know that they access my pages as part of a user transaction (presenting terms from my side for acceptance as part of a download). I told a third party I'd try to find out if it's possible to do such a thing even though I wouldn't be the one doing it. I figured it probably was possible and is in fact fairly simple, but it's beyond my basic HTML knowledge. I'll let him know there are tools that can facilitate it and leave it to him to deal with whoever needs to implement it at the other end.